# Visual Studio 2015 generate signed version

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015, release

I'm using visual studio 2015 and cordova 6.3.0 and I follow this tutorial:  http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-package-publish-readme/#package-the-android-version-of-your-app. 
I filled these two files: build.json and ant.properties with android.keystore.
My project didn't have the file build.json so I created and tryied with ant.properties also, but only builds: android-released-unsigned.apk.
Help me please.

Comment: Are you building with Cordova lower than 5.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only had to make the build.json file in the root folder structure.  Below is the code in it. I did not touch ant.properties.  And in the top of VS, make sure to select the dropdown to release instead of debug, then build.

```
    {
  "android": {
    "release": {
      "keystore": "S:\\visual_studio\\keys\\keystore.keystore",
      "storePassword": "mypassword",
      "alias": "myalias",
      "password": "mypassword",
      "keystoreType": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change to Cordova 6.0.0 and so it generate the release, thanks.